# What dose this "square icon" mean for my imap sent mailbox, in mac mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

Im running OSX 10.13.6

I have a range of email accounts setup in mac mail, mostly google apps for business gmail accounts and iCloud accounts.

I have 1 custom hosted IMAP / SMTP account which for some reason is showing a "square icon" (see below screenshot) in the sidebar for the sent mailbox. The inbox mailbox for this account works, but the sent doesn't.

Any ideas why this might be and what the square icons means ?

[image: SCREENSHOT FROM MAC MAIL SHOWING ISSUE]

Comment: What happens when you click the disclosure triangle on that square?

Comment: @fsb , there is nothing under the disclosure triangle - see screenshot here : https://imgur.com/HR0n2O7

Comment: see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7255547

Comment: I ended up getting around this issue by deleting the mail box, then re adding it